# React passing state argument to function

Tags: reactjs

In a React Class, I'm calling a function that expects an argument:

```
renderColumnChart(chart) {
  console.log('rendering chart');  
  console.log(typeof chart);  // <<<<<<<< OK! I get "Object"
  console.log(chart);  // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<< OK! I get the object in the console
  console.log(chart.title);  // <<<<<<<<< NO! I get the error :(
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <br />
      <Chart
        width={'100%'}
        height={'400px'}
        chartType="Bar"
        loader={<div>Loading Chart...</div>}
        data={[
          ['City', '2010 Population', '2000 Population'],
          ['New York City, NY', 8175000, 8008000],
          ['Los Angeles, CA', 3792000, 3694000],
          ['Chicago, IL', 2695000, 2896000],
          ['Houston, TX', 2099000, 1953000],
          ['Philadelphia, PA', 1526000, 1517000],
        ]}
        options={{
          chart: {
            title: 'Chart Title',
            subtitle: 'Hello World',
          },
          legend: { position: 'none' },
          chartArea: { width: '50%' },
          hAxis: {
            title: 'Total Population',
            minValue: 0,
          },
          vAxis: {
            title: 'City',
          },
        }}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

in my class `render()` function I call the function conditionally, waiting for an API call

```
{this.state.isloading ? (
  <div>
    <h1>Loading...</h1>
  </div>
) : (
  this.renderColumnChart(this.state.reports[0])
)}
```

having set `isLoading` to false after the API call:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.getData();
  this.setState({
    isLoading: false,
  });
}
```

But I'm getting this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`

Which is perplexing because: **why can I log the object but not any of its values**?

Comment: Is `getData()` async?

Comment: `getData` is async, and so  is `setState`. So it won't wait for `getData` to finish before setting `isLoading` to false.  This means it will render the chart before the data is returned from the API. That's why you're getting an undefined error. In terms of why the object seems to be defined, I believe that's just a quirk of the browser console. Even though you get that error, in the background the API call still happens and updates the state. In the console, that means previously printed values get updated

Comment: Also, you have a typo, with `this.state.isloading` but then in the `setState` call you use a camel case:  `isLoading`.

Comment: Simplest fix would be to set the state once the API call returns and you've set the reports data in state

Comment: @Jayce444 You found it!! Thanks so much... this was draining!

Answer (score 1):

It's important to know that Chrome's console in the Developer Tools shows a "live" (i.e. current at the time of expansion) view of the object.

Try the following experiment. Copy and paste the following code into the console in Chrome:

```js
const obj = {};
console.log(obj);
obj.foo = 'bar';
setTimeout(() => obj.bar = 'baz');
```

Initially, it will display as `▶ {}`, but if you expand it, it will show that it has two properties, `foo` and `bar`, both of which were added after the object was logged.

The only sure-fire way of logging an object at the state it is when it is logged is to create a (deep) copy of it. One way to do this is using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`, assuming the entire object is serializable to JSON.

Regarding your question, there is one possibility if your code is exactly as it is in your question, which is that you have a typo in your reference in the `render()` function to `this.state.isloading` when it should be `this.state.isLoading`.

But I suspect that is not the real issue. I suspect that what is happening is during the initial render, the value of `this.state.reports[0]` is `undefined`, if you are initializing `this.state = { reports: [], ...etc... }`. Then, after `getData()` completes asynchronously, you are updating the state, so `this.state.reports = [{ title: 'Foo', ...etc... }]`, effectively. When `render()` is called again by React, it can see the full object.

Finally, as others have said, because `getData()` is asynchronous, you need to move the `this.setState({ isLoading: false })` inside your `getData()` function when or after the `reports` state is set. Alternatively, if you can use `async / await` constructs, make `getData()` async and then `componentDidMount()` becomes:

```js
  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.getData();
    this.setState({ isLoading: false });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

add the `isLoading: false,` inside `getData` after you get a response from the API call, remove it from `componentDidMount`

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.getData();
  //this.setState({
  //  isLoading: false,
  //});
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I my code it is not commented.  I’ll update the code above. @Dave Newton it is an asynchronous function.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and still it does not work.  Interesting that even if I set the ```isLoading``` state to false, and never set it to true, I don't see the "Loading..." <h1> in the browser.  Puzzling.